# Replacing special characters in output style (endnote)

Tags: endnote

I have defined my own output style in Endnote, which I use to generate a consistent filename to save the pdf by. That way, my entire collection of pdfs follows an identical naming format. 
I have the output style selected in the "bibliographic output style" window and use the "preview" option to generate the file name--I then save the file under that name on my system.

This works really well, except for titles that have special characters in them. As a consequence, I still have to replace these characters manually. Rather, I would like to replace the special characters automatically as part of the output style. In particular:
* ":" should be replaced by "__"
* "?" or "!" should be removed
These three characters are problematic for my Windows computer, which is why they need to be replaced.

Is there a way to have these characters replaced automatically as part of an output style?